# Xcode 8 : Can i use Constraints and autosizing both in Single View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, autosize, xcode8

There is autosizing option available until you give any constraints to UI Component.

So can I use both for my ViewController?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could, but you shouldn't

You can use constraints on some views, and autosizing on others, but be careful not to mix them on the same view, as that will cause issues (the autosizing information will be lost).

iOS takes care of autosizing views by creating constraints that convey the information of the autosizing to the constraints engine. This behaviour can be enabled or disabled by the aptly named [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints).

You could try to add constraints to a view and still have it autoresize with the old behaviour by setting this value to `true`, but I suggest you use constraints for every view, as it can do everything the autosizing can, and much more.

Comment: To add on to this: just use constraints, you can use them for most, if not all layouts. Frame setting is a lot of work and should not be done regularly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (use a mixture of constraints and autoresizing on subviews within a single view) within **Xcode 8**.  See:

02:38 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/

With Xcode 8, the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property for each view is automatically maintained by Interface Builder:

- By default, when a child view is first added, the value of the property is true.
- When the first constraint is added to the child view, the value is automatically set to false and the **Size Inspector** pane changes to the **Constraints** view.
- When the last constraint is removed from the child view, the value of the property is automatically reverted to true, and the **Size inspector** reverts to the **Autoresizing** view.

Answer (score 0):

- If you create a view programatically, **Xcode** will generate `constraints` to satisfy `autoresizing` itself (`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `true`). However if you create a view in IB, **Apple** says:

> If you add views in Interface Builder, the
>   system automatically sets this property to false.

- To reflect that, any view added into IB before **Xcode 8** has that `autoresizing` option hidded (or at least I did not see it for a while there).

#### But here is the thing:

- Since **Xcode 8**, the option is visible (`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `true`) until you add any constraint, so the Apple's text above is not actually correct I guess.

So in a single view you **cannot** satisfy/use both. **view(autoresizing and constraints)**

In subviews you can use different for each one, but it will be a mess and I cannot imagine reasonable usage. **view->subview(constraints) and subview(autoresizing)**

That also means that you **can** use e.g. **view(autoresizing)->subview(constraints)**